# how to divide row into <td> in responsive table

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a table like this:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| A  | A  | B  | B  | C  | C  |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

And I need to get this result in small screen

```
+----+----+
| A  | A  |
+----+----+
| B  | B  |
+----+----+
| C  | C  |
+----+----+
```

Is it possible?

I want to use only css, no jquery.
use display: property, td::after
how should I do ?
How can I solve this?

```css
 @media( max-width:640px) {
   #test, #test thead, #test tbody {} #test tr {
     /* ? */
   }
   #test th {
     /* ? */
   }
   #test td {
     /* ? */
   }
   #test td::after {
     /* ? */
   }
   #test tr {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
   }
   #test th,
   #test td {
     border-top: none;
     border-bottom: none;
   }
 }
```

```html
<table id="test" class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <td>A</td>
    <th>B</th>
    <td>B</td>
    <th>C</th>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>D</th>
    <td>D</td>
    <th>E</th>
    <td>E</td>
    <th>F</th>
    <td>F</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

`<table>` and `@media` are not the best friends.
`<div>` instead can be both `display: block;` and `display: table;` if we want to, so let's rock

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/fupabo/1/edit?html,css,output)***

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;}html,body{height:100%;margin:0;}

.table{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-left: 1px solid #444;
  border-top:  1px solid #444;
}
.tr{
  display: table-row;
}
.td,
.th{
  display: table-cell;  
  background: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
  border-right: 1px solid #444;
}
.th{
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media(max-width:640px) {
  .table,
  .tr{
    display: block;
  }
  .th,
  .td{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="th">A</div>
    <div class="td">A</div>
    <div class="th">B</div>
    <div class="td">B</div>
    <div class="th">C</div>
    <div class="td">C</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="th">D</div>
    <div class="td">D</div>
    <div class="th">E</div>
    <div class="td">E</div>
    <div class="th">F</div>
    <div class="td">F</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your comment. the web i made is full of table tag. so it is difficult to change table to div.but i got the hint from your comment. th, td width 50% is the clue. thank you again!!

Comment: There's no clue. Width 50perc will not do what you think will do. Otherwise I would not suggest such a huge remake.

Answer (score 0):

This is using bootstrap:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 text-center">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6">A</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6">A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 text-center">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6">B</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 text-center">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6">C</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6">C</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Its better to use `<div>` rather than using the old `<table>`. Use a framework like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/), styling would be much easier.

Comment: thank you for your comment. the comment is different way to solve it. the comment is that i can't think a way. thank you for your comment again.